# Seg fault when accessing a struct

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault

I put the whole code on github: https://github.com/marianatuma/CG

I have a struct called point, declared in `line.h`, and a class line that has two points, start and end. EDIT: I didn't add it before, but Line inherits from GraphObj. `graphObj.h`:

```
class GraphObj {
private:
    type t;
    std::string name;

public:
    GraphObj(type t, std::string name);
    type getType();
    std::string getName();
};
```

`line.h`:

```
#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

struct point {
    double x;
    double y;
};

class Line {
private:
    point start;
    point end;

public:
    Line(type t, std::string name) : GraphObj(t, name) {};
    void setStart(double x, double y);
    void setEnd(double x, double y);
    point getStart();
    point getEnd();
};
#endif
```

`line.cpp`:

```
#include "line.h"

void Line::setStart(double x, double y) {
    this->start.x = x;
    this->start.y = y;
}

void Line::setEnd(double x, double y) {
    this->end.x = x;
    this->end.y = y;
}


point Line::getStart() {
    return start;
}

point Line::getEnd() {
    return end;
}
```

I always get a segmentation fault when I try accessing any of these points. I tried making them public, didn't work. I also tried using getters and it also didn't work. Here's how I'm initializing them:

The line is in a list of lines, called a display file, which will be used with cairo to draw them.

`displayFile.h`:

```
#ifndef DISPLAYFILE_H
#define DISPLAYFILE_H

#include <list>
#include "graphObj.h"

class DisplayFile {
private:
    std::list<GraphObj*>* objectList;   
    std::list<GraphObj*>::iterator it;
    int size;
public:
    DisplayFile();
    void add(GraphObj* g);
    GraphObj* getNextObject();
    void resetIterator();
    int getSize();
};
#endif
```

`displayFile.cpp`:

```
#include "displayFile.h"

DisplayFile::DisplayFile() {
    this->objectList = new std::list<GraphObj*>();
    this->it = objectList->begin();
    this->size = 0;
}

void DisplayFile::add(GraphObj* g) {
    std::list<GraphObj*>::iterator tempIt;
    tempIt = objectList->begin();
    this->objectList->insert(tempIt, g);
    this->size++;
}

GraphObj* DisplayFile::getNextObject() {
    return *++it;
}

void DisplayFile::resetIterator() {
    it = objectList->begin();
}

int DisplayFile::getSize() {
    return size;
}
```

DisplayFile returns a GraphObj instead of the objectList, so it has to iterate through objectList by itself, hence the resetIterator (so when the main code is done traversing the list it will reset the iterator to the start of the list, but I'm not calling this method anywhere so far). The code in `main.cpp` where an instance of Line is used is below:

```
static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
  /* not using these right now
  cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
  cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.5);
  */

  int size = df->getSize(); //df is the list

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Line* g = df->getNextObject();
    point start = g->getStart();
  }
}
```

The problem only starts when I try accessing the points, I can access other attributes from that line instance without problems. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I hope I've provided enough information, the main code is long and doesn't really have much to do with the line class, so I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: The information is not enough. Please [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so where is start declared ?

Comment: The `(Line*)` old-style cast is suspicious but there's not enough information.

Comment: With a pointer you need to create an instance of the object. Are you doing something like this start = new point(); somewhere before you call g->GetStart()

Comment: I edited the code a bit, I hope this is more comprehensible. The cast was an experimental bit that didn't work. @amisam no, I thought structs didn't need to be initialised like that

Comment: Neither `Line` nor `point` have a default constructor, are you sure the points have valid values before accessing them? Please read the mcve link posted by songyuanyao, your sample code is still incomplete.

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger and checking that `g` is always a valid pointer to a line?

Comment: Is the problem only happening when you are using the point in `do_drawing()` or when you use the `setStart` and `setEnd` to?

Comment: @amisam when I only use setStart and setEnd the seg fault doesn't happen.

Comment: @user657267 I didn't know structs could have a constructor. I added one but it didn't work. Line actually inherits an attribute from another class, but the other class doesn't do anything yet, just has an attribute and the constructor. I'll add it any way

Comment: Demonstration that the problem is not in the code you've shown: http://ideone.com/bvXu6K

Comment: Note that you've stated that `Line` inherits from `GraphObj` but you've not shown that inheritance in the amended code beyond the initializer in the constructor (which won't compile at the moment).  Please study how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — and provide us with compilable code that reproduces the problem.  (You've not shown where `df` comes from, nor how you build the list that it references.  There's a good chance that the problem is in the list handling code rather than in what you show.)

Comment: "Line inherits from GraphObj" not according to your example, `Line` doesn't inherit from anything. Why are you posting code that you aren't actually using? Unless you post something we can reproduce you aren't going to get anywhere.

Comment: The problem is not in the code shown. Since you are getting a segfault I bet you have a dangling pointer in your list implementation.

Comment: You're probably using an uninitialised `Line*`

Comment: So many errors in that list... start by reading [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), you will see you have a lot of nice (already proven) methods to handle elements within the list, i.e.: `push_back`, `push_front` or `size()` for starters (meaning that you _don't have_ to keep track of the size manually for instance). I think you'd be better off replacing the entire `DisplayFile` class with a plain `std::list`

Comment: In this particular case `return *++it;` of method `getNextObject()` is the winner... Think about this, what if `it` already happens to be the last element on the list, and you ask for `getNextObject()`? _Boom_

Comment: For bonus brownie points: you should be using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers in your list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with your list class.

```
class DisplayFile {
private:
    std::list<GraphObj*>* objectList;   // Why not just a list<GraphObj*>
    std::list<GraphObj*>::iterator it;  // Why use this?
    int size;                           // WHY manually keep track of a STL container size?
public:
    DisplayFile();
    void add(GraphObj* g);
    void resetIterator();
    int getSize();
};
```

In your implementation file:

```
GraphObj* DisplayFile::getNextObject() {
    return *++it;
}
```

As I already commented: this is the winner... Think about it, what if `it` already happens to be the last element on the list, and you ask for `getNextObject()`? ***Boom***

---

I don't see why you couldn't just replace the entire `DisplayFile` class with a nice and plain `std::list`:

```
std::list<GraphObj*> objectList;
// I would also advice to change to smart pointers here
// for example: std::list<std::shared_ptr<GraphObj> > objectList;
// or           std::list<std::unique_ptr<GraphObj> > objectList;
```

Then you would just use the STL methods to work with the list:

***Add an item to the front:*** (for the sake of simplicity lets imagine that `GraphObj` has a default constructor)

```
GraphObj* g = new GraphObj();
objectList.push_front(g);
// If you change to smart pointers:
// objectList.push_front(std::make_shared<GraphObj>());
// or
// objectList.push_front(std::make_unique<GraphObj>());
```

***Get the list size:***

`objectList.size();`

***Traverse the list:***

```
for (std::list<GraphObj*>::const_iterator it = objectList.begin();
    it != objectList.end();
    ++it)
{
    point start = (*it)->getStart();
    // or whatever you need to do here
}
```

*Or with the much nicer range for:*

```
for (const auto & graphObj : objectList)
{
    point start = graphObj->getStart();
    // or whatever you need to do here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I definitely made a lot of mistakes there, I never really worked with c++ or c, so I didn't really know what to expect. Thanks again, this was a life-saving answer

Comment: @Marituma I'm glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be coming from your getStart and getEnd because they return a point, which will create a copy(I think) of your start or end point, ie not using the point from line but copies. This usually isn't a big deal but if you want to change an x or y value and have the new value stick you'll need a reference to the original points x and y values.
Try this, change

```
point getStart();
point getEnd();
```

into

```
point *getStart() { return &start; }
point *getEnd()   { return &end;   }
```

and in your do_drawing(cairo_t *cr) change

```
point start = g->getStart();
```

to

```
point *start = g->getStart();
start->x = value;        // or
double value = start->x; // or however you want to use start
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response! unfortunately I still get the segmentation fault when I try to access `start->x`

Comment: @Marutuma You might have to post more of your code then, or if you can find the line that causes the fault then surrounding code. Sometimes we delete objects but still have references to them and when we try use them it can cause the seg fault.

Comment: Is it ok if I post it on github and link it here?

Comment: sure if your allowed to put your code online. Link it in your question so people don't have to find it here

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not initilaizing the structs .

Change your constructor a bit

From this

```
Line(type t, std::string name) : GraphObj(t, name) {};
```

to

```
Line(type t, std::string name) : GraphObj(t, name) , start(),end() {};
```

This may help.

Comment: Thanks Anurag, but I'm still getting the segmentation fault